# Match the closest time stamp within a group in R

Tags: r, datetime, pandas-groupby, fuzzy-search

Assume I have two datasets. Both of them have a common variable - location. Dataset A has time stamp at precision of second level , while Dataset B has time stamp at millisecond level. Is there any efficient way for me to match the two datasets by time interval (e.g. get the most updated weather for Dataset A)for each location in R or python?

Really appreciate any thought or inputs.

Example for Dataset A

| Location | Date | Time | # items |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| New York | 2019-01-01 | 09:00:00 | 50 |
| New York | 2019-01-01 | 09:15:28 | 10 |
| New York | 2019-01-01 | 09:16:16 | 69 |
| New York | 2019-01-01 | 10:09:00 | 47 |
| New York | 2019-01-11 | 19:34:30 | 777 |
| New York | 2019-01-11 | 22:10:15 | 276 |
| ... |  |  |  |
| Miami | 2019-01-01 | 09:00:01 | 100 |
| Miami | 2019-01-01 | 16:07:09 | 145 |
| Miami | 2019-01-01 | 20:05:01 | 56 |
| ... |  |  |  |
| Boston | 2020-12-21 | 23:09:02 | 78 |

Example for Dataset B:

| Location | Date | Time | Weather |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| New York | 2019-01-01 | 05:56:09.456 | Rain |
| New York | 2019-01-01 | 08:59:23.897 | Sunny |
| New York | 2019-01-01 | 09:14:35.897 | Cloudy |
| ... |  |  |  |
| Boston | 2020-12-31 | 23:25:09.987 | Snow |

The idea output would be:

| Location | Date | Time | # items | Weather Time | Weather |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| New York | 2019-01-01 | 09:00:00 | 50 | 08:59:23.897 | Sunny |
| New York | 2019-01-01 | 09:15:28 | 10 | 09:14:35.897 | Cloudy |
| New York | 2019-01-01 | 09:16:16 | 69 | 09:14:35.897 | Cloudy |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: How big are your two datasets and how many matches would a lookup that just relied on exact matches (e.g. for Location and Date) bring up? A brute force approach might work fine here, where you join on Location and Date, and then filter for closest match.

Comment: How to interpret "get the most updated weather for Dataset `A`"? Does it refer to the most recent weather data just _before_ the timestamp in `A`? Or, to the _nearest_ time which may include weather data published _after_  the timestamp in `A`?

Comment: In the initial phase I focused more on the most recent weather data before timestamp in A. But I'm also interested in borrowing your brains for the nearest timestamp practice if possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, dataset `A` should be completed by the most recent available weather data for `Location`  from dataset `B`.

This can by achieved by a *rolling join* and an *update by reference*:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(A)[, dttm := lubridate::ymd_hms(paste(Date, Time))]
setDT(B)[, dttm := lubridate::ymd_hms(paste(Date, Time))]
A[, c("WeatherTime", "Weather") := 
    B[A, on = c("Location", "dttm"), roll = Inf, .(x.dttm, x.Weather)]][]
```

> ```
>     Location       Date     Time # items                dttm         WeatherTime Weather
>  1: New York 2019-01-01 09:00:00      50 2019-01-01 09:00:00 2019-01-01 08:59:23   Sunny
>  2: New York 2019-01-01 09:15:28      10 2019-01-01 09:15:28 2019-01-01 09:14:35  Cloudy
>  3: New York 2019-01-01 09:16:16      69 2019-01-01 09:16:16 2019-01-01 09:14:35  Cloudy
>  4: New York 2019-01-01 10:09:00      47 2019-01-01 10:09:00 2019-01-01 09:14:35  Cloudy
>  5: New York 2019-01-11 19:34:30     777 2019-01-11 19:34:30 2019-01-01 09:14:35  Cloudy
>  6: New York 2019-01-11 22:10:15     276 2019-01-11 22:10:15 2019-01-01 09:14:35  Cloudy
>  7:    Miami 2019-01-01 09:00:01     100 2019-01-01 09:00:01                <NA>    <NA>
>  8:    Miami 2019-01-01 16:07:09     145 2019-01-01 16:07:09                <NA>    <NA>
>  9:    Miami 2019-01-01 20:05:01      56 2019-01-01 20:05:01                <NA>    <NA>
> 10:   Boston 2020-12-21 23:09:02      78 2020-12-21 23:09:02                <NA>    <NA>
> ```

Note that weather data is missing for Miami. The weather data for Boston as provided in the sample data is ten days late.

#### Data

```
A <- structure(list(Location = c("New York", "New York", "New York", 
"New York", "New York", "New York", "Miami", "Miami", "Miami", 
"Boston"), Date = structure(c(17897L, 17897L, 17897L, 17897L, 
17907L, 17907L, 17897L, 17897L, 17897L, 18617L), class = c("IDate", 
"Date")), Time = c("09:00:00", "09:15:28", "09:16:16", "10:09:00", 
"19:34:30", "22:10:15", "09:00:01", "16:07:09", "20:05:01", "23:09:02"
), `# items` = c(50L, 10L, 69L, 47L, 777L, 276L, 100L, 145L, 
56L, 78L)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

B <- structure(list(Location = c("New York", "New York", "New York", 
"Boston"), Date = structure(c(17897L, 17897L, 17897L, 18627L), class = c("IDate", 
"Date")), Time = c("05:56:09.456", "08:59:23.897", "09:14:35.897", 
"23:25:09.987"), Weather = c("Rain", "Sunny", "Cloudy", "Snow"
)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

#### Explanation

- `Date` and `Time` are combined into a continuous `POSIXct` datetime to join on.  This will avoid gaps caused by day change.
- The *rolling join*

  ```
  B[A, on = c("Location", "dttm"), roll = Inf, .(x.dttm, x.Weather)]
  ```

  returns

  > ```
  >                  x.dttm x.Weather
  >  1: 2019-01-01 08:59:23     Sunny
  >  2: 2019-01-01 09:14:35    Cloudy
  >  3: 2019-01-01 09:14:35    Cloudy
  >  4: 2019-01-01 09:14:35    Cloudy
  >  5: 2019-01-01 09:14:35    Cloudy
  >  6: 2019-01-01 09:14:35    Cloudy
  >  7:                <NA>      <NA>
  >  8:                <NA>      <NA>
  >  9:                <NA>      <NA>
  > 10:                <NA>      <NA>
  > ```
- The *update by reference* (`c("WeatherTime", "Weather") := ...`) appends two new columns to dataset `A` *without copying* the whole object. This might help to mitigate ressource limitations.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a brute force approach that might work acceptably if your data doesn't have a huge number of Location-Date matches.

```
library(dplyr); library(lubridate)

# add timestamp to both
Data_A <- Data_A %>% mutate(timestamp = ymd_hms(paste(Date, Time)))
Data_B <- Data_B %>% mutate(timestamp = ymd_hms(paste(Date, Time)))

# join the two tables
Data_A %>%
  left_join(Data_B, by = c("Location", "Date")) %>%

  # calc time diffs and select best match for each Location/Date
  mutate(time_diff = abs(timestamp.x - timestamp.y)) %>%
  group_by(Location, timestamp.x) %>% # EDIT
  arrange(time_diff) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks very much for the input. I am currently using a similar approach for my sample data, however location - date combination is pretty massive that merging the two might gets into a resource constraint issue.

Comment: In that case a "non-equi join" using sqldf, fuzzyjoin, or data.table seems what you need. Many examples on this site.

Comment: @JonSpring, I ran you code for comparison. Is it intended that only one row per `Location` and `Date` is returned, 4 rows in total for OP's sample dataset?

Comment: Thank you. I meant to keep each timestamp from the first table, so I should have grouped by `timestamp.x` instead of `Date`. Edited.